# Suppressing or removing factor levels to improve analysis using Likert package in R

Tags: r, factors, likert

I am trying to analyze a moderate sized survey dataset using the "likert" package and is primarily comprised of Likert Scale questions (Strongly Agree to Strongly Disagree). The problem I am running into.:, there are a fair number of "NAs" and other values that are making my analysis much difficult, such as "Does Not Apply" or "Don't Know". I'm not entirely sure how the best way to go about sub-setting or suppressing those values to make for cleaner summaries and plots.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might also consider asking this question on  Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/. We can help you with the programming aspects of filtering and recording your data, but if you're interested in the most statistically proper way to deal with `NA`s in your data, Cross Validated will likely be more helpful.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the insight. I'll post over there as well.